# fsck not running on ubuntu 18 lts

Tags: 18.04, fsck

I want to `fsck` the 249G volume, because this hdd has got problem booting up. Hoping it can help fix the disk so that it can boot up again. It is my ubuntu boot hdd.

[image: error when click with nautilus]

[image: mounted device "df" result]

**It shows my sda hdd is not mounted.**

[image: lsblk result]

**Sda is the hdd** that I ran ubuntu on, but it has problem, I think even computer can't read it.

The hdd and the content of it are ok. I used "diskinternals linux reader and active disk editor" and able to browse thru all subfolders and data on a windows computer.

[image: fsck error]

How can my sda being in use? Seeing it is not even mounted!

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: `sda1` is the partition where the OS resides, you can't `fsck` this partition unless you run a live system. As shown in your images, the 249 disk is not `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/dm-0`, so you have to run `fsck /dev/dm-0`

Comment: my sda is ruined, can't boot. hence it is as good as no Os in sda. hence i wanted to check disk sda, hopefully it will fix it, so that it will be bootable again.  i am sure sda is the one that i want to fsck.

Comment: What do you mean by ruined? If the problem is the file system you can run a live ubuntu and fsck the disk. If you know that there are bad sector, well, then your hd may be broken.

Comment: file system issue, that's why i want to run fsck on it. but can't

Comment: Hii guillermo chamorro, why my only hdd is mounted in  /dev/dm-0 ? should it be  /dev/sda ?